# UnhandledPromiseRejection while OGM initialize on Neo4j GraphQL Express Server

Tags: express, neo4j, neo4j-ogm, ecmascript-next, ecmascript-2021

I am using express with Neo4j graphql.

Seeing this exception without specific line indications in my code.

```
node:internal/process/promises:289
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "[object Array]".] {   code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION' }

Node.js v20.3.0
```

1. I have graph data models defined in **"graph-data-models.js"**

   ```
    ...        
    const driver = neo4j.driver(
    ...
    );

    const ObjectGraphMap = new OGM({ typeDefs, driver });
    const Challenge = ObjectGraphMap.model("Challenge");
    ...
   ```
2. Express Server on **"app.js"**. Server should start from here. I run `node app.js`.

   ```
   ...
   try {
       await ObjectGraphMap.init();
       app.listen(port, () => {
           logger.info(`Data API App listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
       });
   } catch(e) {
       logger.error("OGM init failed",e);
   }
   ```
3. API Definitions in **"api.js"**

```
...
app = express()
...
app.get("/challenges", getChallenges);
...
```

4. Data Models used in **"api-impl.js"**

```
...
const getChallenges = async (req, res) => {
    try {
      ...  
      Challenge.find({
            ... }
        })
        .then((challenge) => {
           ...
        })
        .catch((err) => {
        ...
        });
    } catch (error) {
        ...
    } 
}
...
```

It looks to me like something more than just wrapping around a try-catch at all places. How can I debug and find out the issue? OGM init needs some change but then-catch model on **"app.js"** like.

```
...
ObjectGraphMap.init()
    .then(() => {
    ...
    }) 
    .catch(() => {
    ...
    })
...
```

does not cut it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue after retracing all the steps I made.
Unfortunately, it is not related to any of the details I had posted. Partly the reason it took me so long to debug.

However, it is not really the solution for it.
I had added a field on schema (which is used to instantiate the driver - variable `typeDefs`). So, `ObjectGraphMap.init()` fails.
Alas, Neo4j does not (yet) have the flexible schema integration with graphql. It may be not that bad as it can get pretty dynamic and error-prone without hard-fixing the schema.

**PS:** Stacktrace needs to improve though. Not actually accepting this as an answer because there seems to be something to address on ES. Check this [out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71500702/the-promise-rejected-with-the-reason-object-array-code-err-unhandled-r) and this [too](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/43326).